# Updating index.android.bundle from remote server in react native [Android]

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am creating a demo react native app that is implementing aeroFS https://github.com/redbooth/react-native-auto-updater library
[An aerofs library is nothing but each time when app opens it will check for update from remote server and if update is available it will download and ask the user to apply for the update without play store].

So far the app is able to download the file but after download i am not able to see any changes in the app.I'm sure the newly downloaded bundle is not used in the activity.

On further checking inside the library i found the following method in ReactNativeAutoUpdaterActivity class (main class):-

```
@Override
@Nullable
public String getJSBundleFile() {
   updater=ReactNativeAutoUpdater.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
   updater.setMetadataAssetName(this.getMetadataAssetName());
   return updater.getLatestJSCodeLocation();
}
```

The ReactNativeAutoUpdaterActivity extends from ReactActivity which does not have this method.I think this is moved to ReactNativeHost so i knew this is the problem but now should i implement my own react native host class to over ride the method so that once new bundle file is downloaded i can apply it to app.

Comment: Still i am struggling with same issue it seems no one knows about this.All i need to do is fetch JSBundle from remote server i am surprise no one required this in react native.

Answer (score 0):

MainApplication.java

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
.
.
.
@Override
  public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    SharedPreferences preferences =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    preferences.edit().putString("debug_http_host", "128.xxx.xxx.xxx:1234").apply();
  }
```

When using a remote VM, port 8081 is not exposed, so:

`npm start -- --reset-cache --port=1234`

AppDelegate.m (iOS):

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://128.xxx.xxx.xxx:1234/index.js"];
```